# Angularjs can't obtain the current state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following in my controller:

```
$scope.state = $state
```

If I do: `console.log($scope.state);` - my **current** object inside state tells me all the information I need, including the name, url, etc. However, I am not able to actually grab it...

because if I do the following:

```
console.log($scope.state.current);
console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.state)));
```

I get this as my current state:

```
{name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true}
```

Does anyone know how I can actually get the current state's name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. Thank you @MathewBerg for explaining why my method didn't.

```
.run(['$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
  function ($rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
    $rootScope.$state = $state;
    $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;
}])
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because when you console log you get a reference. So by the time you open the object and look at it in the console it's probably already been filled.

```
var state = { current: {name: "", url: "^", views: null, abstract: true},  otherData: [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}] };

console.log(state);
console.log(state.current);
console.log(JSON.stringify(state));

state.current.name = 'something';
```

jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xfqbc6yr/

In the console for chrome you'll see an object that you can expand, the current state object (where it will be empty) and then a stringified where it will also be empty. If you expand the first object you'll see that the name has changed to 'something'.

Comment: That makes no sense because if I do all 3 of those console logs, `$scope.state` gives me what I need. Why wouldn't the stringify version or going one step deeper give me that also?

Comment: I'm sorry you don't believe me. I have included a fiddle to show you.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to actually get the current state?

Comment: I can't see the rest of your code so I'm unsure where it's changing. You could do an angular watch `$scope.watch('state', function(){ ... }, true);` and then in the function is when it changes, you can check if current is set there.

Comment: Yea I guess i'm still just not understanding why `state.current` would be empty if `state` isn't. Your fiddle is just exactly what I wrote in my answer. I understand it's happening just have no idea why.

Comment: Because console.log is a reference. But since your state.current is such a small object it doesn't have the expanding on it and show it shows what it is at that time.

Comment: Why in the world would `state` and `JSON.stringify(state)` ever be different. It's making my brain hurt. I know i'm missing something crucial here so sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Look into what a reference is. JSON.stringify is going to show you what state is at that EXACT moment (therefore empty). While state is an object/reference so when you view it in the console it's probably already been updated. There's not much more I can explain, I'm sorry.